# How to fix third party dll include not being staged correctly by Unreal Build Tool?

Tags: dll, build, package, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am using a pre-built C++ library in my Unreal project using a dynamic library file (let's say it's called `MyPluginLib.dll`). The library is contained in a plugin, let’s call it `MyPlugin`.

Building, packaging, playing in editor works fine. However, a **packaged build doesn’t start**, giving the following error: `Code execution cannot proceed, MyPluginLib.dll was not found`.

The packaging process places `MyPluginLib.dll` file in `MyGame\Plugins\MyPlugin\Binaries`. However, the execution process is seemingly looking for it in `MyGame\Binaries` – **moving the library there manually solves this issue**.

**Why is the OS unable to find the dll in the first folder?** Is there something wrong in the build.cs, or my folder structure?

The folder structure of the plugin folder is as follows:

- Includes in `Plugins\MyPlugin\Source\ThirdParty\MyPluginLib\`
- Binaries in `Plugins\MyPlugin\Binaries\(PLATFORM)\`

The plugin’s `Build.cs` looks like this:

```
public class MyPlugin : ModuleRules
{
    public MyPlugin(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PCHUsage = ModuleRules.PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;

        string PluginRoot = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(ModuleDirectory, "..", ".."));
        string PlatformString = Target.Platform.ToString();
        string LibraryDirectory = Path.Combine(PluginRoot, "Binaries", PlatformString);

        PublicIncludePaths.Add(Path.Combine(PluginRoot, "Source", "ThirdParty", "MyPluginLib"));

        if ((Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Win64))
        {
            PublicAdditionalLibraries.Add(Path.Combine(LibraryDirectory, "MyPluginLib.lib"));
            RuntimeDependencies.Add(Path.Combine(LibraryDirectory, "MyPluginLib.dll"), StagedFileType.NonUFS);
        }
        else if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Linux)
        {
            // linux binaries...
        }
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your packaged games files, unreal loves to not include certain thing in packaged builds regarding plugins.